# Docusign getUserInfo returns empty accounts list

Tags: docusignapi

We have a fairly simple docusign integration application (written in Java) which works without problems on developer account. App is simply sending pdf document to several emails for signature.

Now once we switched to production, it does not work anymore. I was not original developer of this integration, but did some debugging, and what I can observe is following:

- on development environment - a call to getUserInfo will return userinfo details (name, email, id,..) with accounts data.
- on production environment - a call to getUserInfo will return userinfo details (name, email, id,..) but no accounts data (empty list).

Production call fails with error message:

`com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Missing the required parameter 'accountId' when calling createEnvelope`

I am new to Docusign integration, so any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a known issue that impacts a specific set of users. Please see https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Empty-UserInfo for more information, and open a case with DocuSign Support as per the enclosed instructions to get this resolved. Select APIs & Development as the case category.

```
To resolve this issue, open a DocuSign Support case referencing issue PROV-571 in the Case Comments and include the following information:

Whether the issue occurring in Demo or Production
UserID and email address of the impacted user
Known account IDs for the impacted user
Integration Key used
```

Comment: Opening up a ticket indeed resolved the problem. It was something on the DocuSign side, apparently somehow the had more then one account on my email or something like that.

Comment: Yeah. Normally having multiple accounts under an email is fine, but there's a few older memberships that are in a bad state that block that call. Support can fix these on their side, but unfortunately DocuSign wasn't able to take a bulk action to resolve them all in one sweep.